# How to match the information with the regex expression inside the html tag if the tag is repeating?

Tags: java, regex, eclipse

Like if I have the tags

```
<td class="cit-borderleft cit-data">437</td>
<td class="cit-borderleft cit-data">394</td>
<td class="cit-borderleft cit-data">12</td>
<td class="cit-borderleft cit-data">**12**</td>
```

But I need to match number 12 in the last tag. I am using the regex expression `"<td class=\"cit-borderleft cit-data\">(.*?)</td>"` but it will match all four of the tags.

Comment: Is `**` really part of your input, or did you try to make that `12` bold in your example? Also is there any reason why you don't want to use proper HTML/XML parser and decided to use regex?

Comment: Parsing HTML with regular expressions will just end in tears, use a proper HTML parser as suggested in one of the answers.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use regex. Use proper XML/HTML parser like [jsoup](https://jsoup.org/). If you simply want to get text from last element of type `td` with classes `cit-borderleft cit-data` you can use

```
String html = 
        "<table>" +
        "<td class=\"cit-borderleft cit-data\">437</td>\r\n" + 
        "<td class=\"cit-borderleft cit-data\">394</td>\r\n" + 
        "<td class=\"cit-borderleft cit-data\">12</td>\r\n" + 
        "<td class=\"cit-borderleft cit-data\">**12**</td>" +
        "</table>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
Element last = doc.select("td.cit-borderleft.cit-data").last();
System.out.println(last.text());
```

Output: `**12**`

If you then want to remove these `*` simply call `replace("*","")` on that string and you will get new one without asterisks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<td class=\"cit-borderleft cit-data\">\*\*(.*?)\*\*<\/td>
```

or simple way, this:

```
\*\*(\d+)\*\*
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your attempt

```
<td class=\"cit-borderleft cit-data\">(.*?)<\/td>(?![\s\S]*<\/td>)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/387)
added this part `(?![\s\S]*<\/td>)`

```
(?!             # Negative Look-Ahead
  [\s\S]        # Character in [\s\S] Character Class
  *             # (zero or more)(greedy)
  <             # "<"
  \/            # "/"
  td>           # "td>"
)               # End of Negative Look-Ahead
```

Answer (score 0):

[I don't get why you're using [tag:regex] to parse an HTML tag but here it is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

### [Regex101
`(?<=<td class=\"cit-borderleft cit-data\">\*\*)\d*(?=\*\*<\/td>)`](https://regex101.com/r/zP7vO6/1)